# wp_get_attachment_image returns different image size

Tags: ajax, wordpress, thumbnails

It is a bug?

```
wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'post-thumb-size-small');
```

Same code, called in template, and in AJAX call returns same image SRC, but different image width and height.

dump from template call:

```
<img width="286" height="189" src="http://localhost/site/files/2012/02/post-image-31-286x189.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumb-size-small" alt="post-image-3" title="post-image-3">
```

dump from AJAX call

```
<img width="220" height="145" src="http://localhost/site/files/2012/02/post-image-31-286x189.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumb-size-small" alt="post-image-3" title="post-image-3">
```

i'm confused, whats wrong?

index.php code

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php include 'post.php'; ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

post.php code

```
<div class="container">

<?php

  $theme->theme_post->display_post_element( $post_type, $post_size, $post);

?>
</div>
```

display_post_element function code

```
    function display_post_element( $post_type, $post_size, $post) {
$attachment_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_view_attachment_id', true);
        if( $post_type == 'single_image') {
            $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full');

            if( is_array( $img)):                
            ?>
            <div class="preview-thumb">
                <a href="<?php echo $img[0]; ?>" class="lightbox"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'post-thumb-size-' . $post_size); ?></a>
                <a href="<?php echo $img[0]; ?>" class="lightbox zoom"></a>
            </div>
            <?php
            endif;
        }
}
```

load posts with ajax call code:

```
function load_posts_ajax() {
    global $post;
    $query_string = $_POST['query_string'];

    query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=' . get_option( 'posts_per_page') . '&post_status=publish&offset=' . (int)$_POST[ 'off']);

    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        include TEMPLATEPATH . '/post.php';
    endwhile; endif;

    die;
}
```

i defined image sizes in functions.php in theme constructor.
i dumped get_intermediate_image_sizes() and all image sizes are loaded in AJAX call

Answer (score 0):

Weird...have you tried to set the size with an array?

```
wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, array(220,145)); // for 220x145
```

Answer (score 0):

It is, indeed, a bug. I've encountered the same problem, and since we had a similar circumstance I figure it has something to do with the AJAX call--who knows why it returns the wrong dimensions, though. ***But***, I figured out a workaround, and though this is a fairly old question, I thought someone else may encounter this issue.

My solution was this:

First, you get the image's url with [wp_get_attachment_image_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src).

`$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'image size name');`

(You can get the attachment ID(s) with [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).)

You then have the URL to the image in `$image[0]`. So what I did was put in the correct dimensions:

`<img src="'.$image[0].'" width="960" height="300" />`

It's not ideal, but at least it works. It may be fixed in WP 3.5 but I wouldn't know, I'm still using 3.4.2.

Comment: This is still an issue in WP 4.0. I need the correct size and cant go image by image. Did you find any other workaround? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it the `editor_max_image_size` at the end of the `image_constrain_size_for_editor()` in **media.php**? It's known to mess with the output of the `wp_get_attachment_image()`.

```
function bypass_editor_max_image_size(){
    if(!empty($width) && !empty($height)){
        return array($width, $height);
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
```

Then later add/remove this around your call to get image src and size.

```
add_filter('editor_max_image_size', array($this, 'bypass_editor_max_image_size'));
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($photo, $size);
remove_filter('editor_max_image_size', array($this, 'bypass_editor_max_image_size'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove the autogenerated inline height and width by insert this couple of line inside functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image', 'remove_width_attribute', 10 );
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_width_attribute', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_width_attribute', 10 );

function remove_width_attribute( $html ) {
   $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)="\d*"\s/', "", $html );
   return $html;
}
```